# How May I extract this ternary operator in independent statement

Tags: c#

Somehow this code looks messy to me:

```
 var results = query.GroupBy(x => x.ProductStatusId == ProductStatus.Sold || x.ProductStatusId == ProductStatus.OnHold ? "Delivered" :
                                x.ProductStatusId == ProductStatus.Shiped ? "Shiped" :
                                x.ProductStatusId == ProductStatus.NotAvailable ? "NotAvailable" :
                                x.ProductStatusId == ProductStatus.Paid ? "Paid" : "New").Where(g => g.Key != "New")
```

Is it possible to extract this ternary operator in independent statement.

Thanks!

Cheers

Comment: How about switch case or the new switch expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another alternative to the switch statement suggested by jakubiszon is a dictionary:

```
var statusMap = new Dictionary<ProductStatus, string>
{
    [ProductStatus.Sold]            = "Delivered",
    [ProductStatus.OnHold]          = "Delivered",
    [ProductStatus.Shiped]          = "Shiped",
    [ProductStatus.NotAvailable]    = "NotAvailable",
    [ProductStatus.Paid]            = "Paid",
}

var results = query
                .Where(i => statusMap.ContainsKey(i.ProductStatusId)
                .GroupBy(x => statusMap[i.ProductStatusId]);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do `query.GroupBy(MyTernaryWrapperMethod)` and declare that method as

```
string MyTernaryWrapperMethod(xVariableType x)
{
    if(x.ProductStatusId == ProductStatus.Sold || x.ProductStatusId == ProductStatus.OnHold) return "Delivered";

    if(x.ProductStatusId == ProductStatus.Shiped) return "Shiped";

    if(x.ProductStatusId == ProductStatus.NotAvailable) return "NotAvailable";

    if(x.ProductStatusId == ProductStatus.Paid) return "Paid";

    return "New"
}
```

But, that method seems to return something being an actual property of x. So maybe you should add a new method to x's type. Also it would be better to use `swicth/case` instead of those `if`s:

```
public string ProductStatusName()
{
    switch (ProductStatusId)
    {
        case ProductStatus.Sold:
        case ProductStatus.OnHold: return "Delivered";
        case ProductStatus.Shiped: return "Shiped";
        case ProductStatus.NotAvailable: return "NotAvailable";
        case ProductStatus.Paid: return "Paid";
        default: return "New"
    }
}
```

And then you do:

```
var results = query.GroupBy(x => x.ProductStatusName()).Where(g => g.Key != "New")
```